# 2 switching inputs to 3 outputs

Tags: motor

I have 2 input pins i1 & i2 they drive a motor forward and reverse by switching states
if i1 is 0v then i2 is 24v forward state
If i1 is 24v then i2 is 0v reverse state
Capable of delivering 3A

I want to change this to 3 pins
o1 = 24v
o2 = 0v
o3 = 0v      in forward state

o1 = 0v
o2 = 0v
o3 = 24v.    In reverse state

Looking for the easiest solution, was thinking 2 diodes ( is that possible)

Voltage is DC

Comment: Sorry I am not following your question. Why do you need three o/p pins. As it is o2 = 0V for both states. What is the engineering problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Still looks like 2 output pins to me, o2 = 0v regardless of input state, so can be hard wired to ground.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you want the new o2 to be the motor current return in both cases. Then you can do what you want with 2 dpst relays and 2 diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSiZPe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>